# How to filter a query on the results of another one in django?

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-queryset, django-orm

Lets say that i have 2 models :

```
Class OrderEvent(models.Model):
    isPaid = models.Booleanfield()


Class Participant(models.Model):
    orderEvent = models.ForeignKey(OrderEvent)
    participantFirstName = models.CharField()
    participantLastName = models.CharField()
    #etc...
```

And i want to get all the participants where Orderevent.isPaid = True.

I think that i struggle to do something very simple...

Comment: `Participant.objects.filter(orderEvent__isPaid = True)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is very simple;

```
Participant.objects.filter(orderEvent__isPaid=True)
```

As a suggestion you can follow,

naming conventions from [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/internals/contributing/writing-code/coding-style/#model-style).

Django making queries from [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships).